# ScalaPB with SparkSQL using Maven

Tags: apache-spark-sql, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use [ScalaPB with SparkSQL](https://trueaccord.github.io/ScalaPB/sparksql.html). I am using Maven in Intellij.

Can somebody please tell me what is the equivalent of 
`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.2")` in Maven.